# No fields visible for Nested form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm trying to create a nested group for customer profiles with multiple billing addresses and postal addresses.When I browse to the customer profile form I see the fields for the Customer profile form but I do not see any fields for the Billing Address form or Postal Address form. Any ideas? my controller, models and view are below.

The goal is to have one customer profile which can  multiple billing addresses and multiple postal addresses.

customer profile model:

```
    class CustomerProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
        #These entries are required to create a nested model form (multiple models in one form)
        validates_presence_of :customerNumber
        validates_uniqueness_of :customerNumber


        has_many :billing_addresses, :dependent => :destroy
        has_many :postal_addresses,  :dependent => :destroy

        accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_addresses, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :postal_addresses, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
    end
```

billing address model:

```
    class BillingAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :customer_profile
        attr_protected :customerNumber
    end
```

postal address model:

```
    class PostalAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :customer_profile
        attr_protected :customerNumber
    end
```

customer profile controller:

```
    def new
        @customer_profile = CustomerProfile.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @customer_profile }
        end
    end


    def create
        @customer_profile = CustomerProfile.new(params[:customer_profile])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @customer_profile.save
            format.html { redirect_to @customer_profile, notice: 'Customer profile was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @customer_profile, status: :created, location: @customer_profile }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @customer_profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
    end
```

customer profile form:

```
    <br />
    <h3>Add new customer profile with Billing and Postal Address</h3>
    <br />
    <h4> Customer Profile </h4>
    <%= form_for @customer_profile do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :customerNumber %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :customerNumber %>
        </div>

        #.... a few other fields removed to keep this short

    <br />
        <h4> Billing Address </h4>
        <%= f.fields_for :billing_addresses do |b| %>

            <div class="field">
                <%= b.label :addressLine1 %><br />
                <%= b.text_field :addressLine1 %>
            </div>

        #.... a few other fields removed to keep this short

        <% end %>

        <br />
        <h4> Postal Address </h4>
        <br />
        <%= f.fields_for :postal_addresses do |p| %>

            <div class="field">
                <%= p.label :addressLine1 %><br />
                <%= p.text_field :addressLine1 %>
            </div>

        #.... a few other fields removed to keep this short

        <br />
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Writing f.fields_for :postal_addresses || PostalAddress.new should fix the form visibility. But if you want to handle creating/editing multiple model associations you should create separate controllers and actions for those.

Comment: @shrimpsushi, thanks for checking the code. I have added the syntax you recommended, however it now does not render the form at all.

Comment: @shrimpsushi I forgot to mention I do have models setup for billing_address and postal_address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields_for will show fields for billing_addresses that are children of the customer_profile.  If this is a new object, you'll either need to add one or more, or - add the appropriate fields through JavaScript. You may want to to both, so there's an empty fields when they get there, then they can add more after.

You can do a `@customer_profile.billing_addresses.build` to have an empty one when the form is rendered.

Do you know how to add and remove fields via javascript?  It's covered well on railscasts.

Comment: I haven't looked into doing this through javascript. I will see what I can find on railscasts though thanks. I tried adding @customer_profile.billing_addresses.build to the new and create methods of Customer_Profile_controller but I then receive the error unknown attribute: customer_profile_id